# active function of navbar using jquery not working

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have recently got into web design. Have got a reasonable understanding of HTML and CSS but still a beginner on jquery/javascript. I was trying to develop a navbar for my website. After researching and watching a lot of videos I created a page on the navbar, but there seems to be some error in my code. The active function doesn't work. All I want is that whatever page I am on, the button of that page should be highlighted in a different color so that it's evident that what page I am on?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .container {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        ul.navmenu {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        ul.navmenu li.active a,
        ul.navmenu li.active:hover a {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
        }

        ul.navmenu {
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #333;
        }

        ul.navmenu li {
            float: left;
        }

        ul.navmenu li a {
            display: block;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        ul.navmenu li:hover a {
            float: left;
            background-color: #111;
        }

        ul.navmenu li:last-child {
            float: right;
        }

    </style>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <ul class='navmenu'>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="page3.html">Page 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="page4.html">Page 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="page5.html">Page 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="page6.html">Page 6</a></li>
            <li><a href="page7.html">Page 7</a></li>
            <li><a href="page8.html">Page 8</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h1>This is Home Page</h1>

    <!-- <script src="jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script>
        $('.navmenu').on('click', 'li', function() {
            $('.navmenu li.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        })

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have real links that point to urls so the javaScript code will not execute, you will navigate to different page. In order to prevent the event you will need to return false when clicking on a element or call `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: That's fantastic jcubic, thanks a lot for your great help

Comment: Sorry, now a new problem has come up. Previously, my href was working i.e. i could switch over to a different page by clicking that page button in navbar but button was not getting active. Now, by using "event.preventDefault()" function, the button gets active but the href is not working i.e. when i click on a button the color of the button changes but it doesn't take me to that page.

Comment: You can't do both, if you navigate away to different url using link you can't modify the the document. If you want to use navigation like this, you will need to use something called Ajax. It's HTTP request done in the browser without reloading the page. You send request to your page, get response and swap the  content and your nav will stay the same. This is standard way of doing this things. Read about Ajax with jQuery to learn more.